# How to install vinyl flooring around rough edge fireplace?

Tags: flooring, fireplace, installation, vinyl-flooring

I am wanting to replace my carpet with vinyl plank flooring but I have a stone fireplace that is kind of jagged stone at the bottom. I am hoping to be able to do the installation myself but don’t know how to install the flooring around this fireplace. Part of it is also a semi-circle so I am having to work with that as well. Any advice is appreciated[image]

Comment: Are you planning for this to be a floating floor, or fastened to the subfloor?

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that can help you to transfer (copy) the irregular edge to vinyl plank to create the cutting guide.

They are called `Contour Duplicator`

Simple to use and look like this.

[image: contur]

Answer (score 0):

The magic word is **scribing.** The non-magical reality is you'll need some patience as well as knowing what to do, once you learn about scribing things to fit an irregular surface, as follows:

You set the piece of flooring you are working with in proper alignment to the rest of the installed flooring near the irregular surface, and set a pair of dividers (or a pencil compass) so it reaches from the deepest part of the irregular surface to the flooring, then trace along the irregular surface while holding the dividers or compass so the other end makes a line the same shape as the irregular surface on the flooring - then you cut that out with a coping saw or similar tool.